# Formatting code to print a string instead of decimal

Tags: java, format, printf

Say I have this print statement,

```
System.out.printf("%+2.1fx^%d", sum, m == 1 ? 0 : m--);
```

My previous code doesn't matter since I am only trying to print something else.

Which prints this:

```
S(x)=-1.5x^5-7.1x^4+4.9x^3+1.4^2+2.4x^0
```

Is there a way to print `" "` (empty space) instead of `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
if (m == 1)
    System.out.printf("%+2.1fx ", sum);        
else
    System.out.printf("%+2.1fx^%d", sum, m--);
```